# Ember sort by attribute on relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application, a `user` can be related to another `user`, and the relationship `status` can be either `accepted`, `pending`, `declined`, and no relationship.

In my database, I have a `users` table, and a `relationships` table.

```
Users Table
- id

Relationships Table
- id
- from_user_id
- to_user_id
- status
```

In Ember, how can I get all `users` and sort by the relationship `status`?

Comment: A use has multiple relationship statuses. Which one do you want to sort by?

Comment: @torazaburo all of them. I would like to start with no relationships, then show accepted, then pending, then declined.

Comment: This isn't so much an Ember.js question as a JavaScript/algorithmic question. I suggest adding what you have tried already.